# Handle `onClick` event using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux so just trying to apply redux to a very simple app. It just toggles the word whenever the button is clicked. But how should I dispatch my `handleClick` function except the action? For now nothing happens when I click the button.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

import MyButton from "./MyButton";
import { handleClick } from "./actions"; 

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    if (this.state.text === "initial text") {
      this.setState({ text: "" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: "initial text" });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyButton onClick={()=>this.props.handleClick('hi')} />
        <p>{this.props.text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    text: state.text
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleClick: () => dispatch(handleClick)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

MyButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MyButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            Click Me!
            </button>;
  }
}

export default MyButton;
```

actions.js

```
export const handleClick = text => ({
  type: "test_action",
  payload: { ...text }
});
```

reducers.js

```
export const reducer = (state = {text:'initial_text'}, action) => {
  if(action.type === 'test_action') {
    return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
  }
  return state; 
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; 
import { createStore } from 'redux'; 

import { reducer } from "./reducers"; 
import App from "./App"; 

import "./styles.css";

const store = createStore(reducer); 

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an argument to your handleClick function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleClick: (text) => dispatch(handleClick(text))
})
```

or just:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { handleClick }
```

Your action is spreading a string inside an object, you should use it as-is:

```
export const handleClick = text => ({
  type: "test_action",
  payload: text
});
```

And your reducer is setting the whole state, instead of just the text property. You can avoid the confusion by splitting then recomining the reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export const text = (state='', action) => {
  if(action.type === 'test_action') {
    return action.payload;
  }
  return state; 
}

export const reducer = combineReducers({
  text
})
```

Comment: object.assign should copy the entire state so, that should not be a problem

Comment: That would not be a problem if action.payload had a text property, but it doesn't

Comment: Also doing this `{ ...text }` with text being a string will return the text splitted to an array of letters

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the mapDispatchToProps `handleClick` prop in the above code does not accept arguments

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleClick: (val) => dispatch(handleClick(val)) // update here so that the 'hi' text is passed to the action creator
})

<MyButton onClick={()=>this.props.handleClick('hi')} />
```

**Update**

The state is not updated correctly

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { text: action.payload }) //pass an object and not just the value
```